# organize or automate code for serial port

Tags: c++, data-structures, serial-port, uart

I wrote a DLL file in C++ that uses "windows.h" to talk to a serial port, and this DLL file loaded with my WPF app - everything works well.

my problem is that the commands(packets of data I send via serial port to the device) are changed every week or two and are still in the developing process. I'm a new developer and I'm thinking to myself is there any way that I can automate the process of making commands for the device and structure my code according to that? or there is any good tool/data structure that will help?

The part that talks to the device I wrote in C++. The WPF app is in C#. The WPF app doesn't interest just the DLL file.

Comment: Can you use an independent representation of commands that can be converted into code? Kaitai struct is my go-to format for defining these things.

Comment: It sounds to me that the DLL should be more low-level (i.e. sending/receiving arbitrary data) such that the encoding/decoding is up to the application. However, it is difficult to say without knowing more about the problem. I think you need to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Side note: you can use nice CommonCPP (https://www.gnu.org/software/commoncpp/) library. It has lowlevel classes for Serial and other interfaces. Portable, so you may run this on Windows, Android, etc.